# Making it efficient: Android Parcelables, Interfaces and Lists

Tags: android, parcelable

The question is: how to implement parceling efficiently on parcelables which implement an interface.

I have this case. An interface that is implemented by two concrete classes (see Picture below) and a container that should be Parcelable (PictureProviders).

The questions is: how to parcel efficiently the list of pictures?

1. We cannot use read/writeTypedList because we won't know which creator to pass to readTypedList.
2. We can use read/writeParcelableArray, but that means to copy the List to an array. Also which class loader would you use? would getClass().getClassLoader() be ok?
3. We could also use read/writeList. Which class loader would you use? would getClass().getClassLoader() be ok?

Sample code:

```
public interface PictureProvider extends Parcelable {
  public Collection<Picture> getAvailablePictures(); 
}

public class SimplePictureProvider implements PictureProvider {

  // ...

  private List<Picture> pictures;

  public SimplePictureProvider(Parcel in) {
    // THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION APPLIES
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // THIS IS WHERE THE QUESTION APPLIES
  }

  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<SimplePictureProvider> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SimplePictureProvider>() {
    public SimplePictureProvider createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new SimplePictureProvider(in);
    }

    public SimplePictureProvider[] newArray(int size) {
      return new SimplePictureProvider[size];
    }
  };
}

public interface Picture extends Parcelable {
  public byte[] getPictureData();
}

public class RemotePicture implements Picture {

  // ...

  private String pictureUrl;

  public RemotePicture(Parcel in) {
    pictureUrl = in.readString();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(pictureUrl);
  }

  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<RemotePicture> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RemotePicture>() {
    public RemotePicture createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new RemotePicture(in);
    }

    public RemotePicture[] newArray(int size) {
      return new RemotePicture[size];
    }
  };
}

public class LocalPicture implements Picture {

  // ...

  private String picturePath;

  public LocalPicture(Parcel in) {
    picturePath = in.readString();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(picturePath);
  }

  public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<LocalPicture> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LocalPicture>() {
    public LocalPicture createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new LocalPicture(in);
    }

    public LocalPicture[] newArray(int size) {
      return new LocalPicture[size];
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used read/writeList with getClass().getClassLoader()? That seems to do the job.

Comment: And what if you want to pass a list of various implementations of PictureProvider?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `writeParcelableArray`, if you know the size won't change and `*List` if the size changes dynamically. Pass `null` as the classloader to use the base/default classloader.